# Express: Send info back to the client

Tags: angular, api, express, post, request

So what i want is, that when i make an Http Post request (Registration form) with angular, it gets processed in the API, and if theres a problem like *Please enter an username...*, i want to send an error message back to the client. I gave you the angular code if you need it. Thanks!

Angular:

```
  sendData(data: {username: string, password: string, bdate: Date}){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', });
  let options = { headers: headers };

    let JsonData:any = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(JsonData)
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/register', JsonData, options)
    .subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Request the data from the TypeScript

```
this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/register', options)
.subscribe(response => {
let usernameError = response.usernameError;
})
```

**Api:**

```
app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
let dataToSend = {
usernameError: 'Please enter a username!',
}
// send the data
res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
})
```